# How can I apply specific functions to pivot tables in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table

I have some data that looks like this:

| Item | Mass | CGx | CGy | CGz | Option |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A123 | 10 | 4.2 | 0.1 | 0.5 | AB01 |
| C789 | 24 | 2.2 | 0.0 | 0.2 | CD02 |
| B456 | 12 | 3.8 | 0.0 | 0.7 | AB01 |
| D123 | 26 | 1.2 | 1.0 | 0.2 | CD02 |

If I want to get the total mass of all items, as well as the center of mass, I can fairly easily use built-in Excel functions to do so. Specifically, if this were a table, I could use:

Total Mass = SUM(Table[Mass])

Total CGx = SUMPRODUCT(Table[Mass], Table[CGx]) / Total Mass

Total CGy = SUMPRODUCT(Table[Mass], Table[CGy]) / Total Mass

Total CGz = SUMPRODUCT(Table[Mass], Table[CGz]) / Total Mass

The problem is that I would like to have this summarized in a pivot table with rows based on the "Option," so something like:

| Option | Mass | CGx | CGy | CGz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB01 | 22 | 4.0 | 0.1 | 0.6 |
| CD02 | 50 | 1.7 | 0.5 | 0.2 |

The mass column is easy to get a sum from the pivot table, but I have no idea how to apply custom functions to do a SUMPRODUCT() for the CG values returned by the pivot filtering on the option column.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use SUMPRODUCT on the pivot table data ranges. Unfortunately, when the pivot updates, or you change a filter setting, the ranges do not seem to update correctly. To compensate, you can create your own [dynamic ranges](https://exceljet.net/formula/dynamic-named-range-with-index) that sizes automatically as the pivot table changes like so:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$4:INDEX($B4:$B100,COUNTA($B4:$B100)-1),C$4:INDEX(C4:C100,COUNTA(C4:C100)-1))
```

With the pivot setup like this
[image]

Alternatively, you can use GETPIVOTDATA to extract selected data from the pivot, creating your own sub-table to use your complex formulae on. In desperate times, I have also resorted to simply copying the whole pivot table data into a new sheet (paste as value), creating a static copy of the data which can be manipulated as normal.

Comment: In the example above, I only had two different options in that column, but my actual dataset has quite a few unique options, so extracting the data, making a sub table (for each), and applying that calculation would be extremely tedious and unsustainable

Comment: Indeed, updated the solution with more detail on the dynamic range method of calculating on pivot table data. For very fancy pivot tables with line breaks, subtotals and in-between headers, you could build up the dynamic array to say start at row 4 but end at a row labelled "Subtotal".

Comment: I realized I made a typo in the formulas for calculating the CGs (now updated), but the method you suggested doesn't seem to provide the correct values for the CGs. In the second table in my question, you can see what the numbers should be, and there are two separate rows, one for the AB01 option and one for the CD02 option. The SUMPRODUCT in the example you showed is performing the calculation on the sums in the pivot table.

Comment: Hmm I think I misunderstood what you were trying to do. I thought you wanted to filter data with the pivot then use formula on the pivoted data. To do your own sumproduct in the pivot might require to add a total column to the original data sheet which is simply the product of the mass and CGx on one row. If you pivot that it will add up to the total CGx, and just needs a /totalmass using a getpivotdata call.

Comment: Alternatively have a look at calculated fields in pivot tables e.g. https://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-calculated-field.html